# Kinesis Agent Input - Log file created for each day

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-kinesis-kpl, amazon-kinesis-agent, apache-camel-aws-kinesis

New Log file is created for each day with date appended in the name. For example "data_log-2017-05-14" log file is created for 14th May.

I need to set up Kinesis Agent to read data from the logs generated. But since each day a new log file is created, how to handle this in agent.json file?

Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 2):

The Kinesis Agent is able to support file patterns and log rotation.

```
{ 
  "flows": [
    { 
      "filePattern": "/tmp/app.log*", 
      "deliveryStream": "yourdeliverystream"
    } 
  ] 
}
```

Please refer to this link for more info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/writing-with-agents.html